# Detect which line failed JSON schema validation in Python

Tags: python, json, schema, jsonschema

I am using the `jsonschema Draft7Validator` in Python and can get all the different validation error data [as documented](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors/#jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError.cause).

Is there any way to get the line number of where an error was detected in the original JSON? I see this sort of functionality in some javascript tools online, but it isn't immediately apparent in Python.

Can I do any better than using the error data to parse the original file and generate the line number manually?

Comment: Would the path help? The latest json schema specification has a defined error format, which includes the json path (in both the data and the schema) for each error.

Comment: That doesn't help if the poster wants to use `draft-07`.

Comment: `draft-07` is the latest supported by `jsonschema`